# I cannot show my firebase database data in my edit text view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried using the following if statement, but the only values that it returns are the URL for my image link:

[image: my database]

```
reference.child("Businesses").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.exists())
    {
        String businessName = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        editTextBusinessName.setText(businessName);

        String businessAbout = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        editTextAbout.setText(businessAbout);

        String businessAddress = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        editTextAddress.setText(businessAddress);

        String businessContactPerson = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        editTextContactPerson.setText(businessContactPerson);

        String businessContactNumber = snapshot.getValue().toString();
        editTextContactNumber.setText(businessContactNumber);
    }
```

Comment: In both snippets, please stop ignoring possible errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: Firstly, if you converting snapshot to values, better to use models to map data.
If your data is not showing check your database and whether it has current user node in the Businesses. Then try printing the snapshot value in onDataChange

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the Exception(), still not working out.

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur I am a beginner :-), can you please elaborate on how to use models to map data

Comment: @ShaunSingh1410 Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the updated code. That also gives you a chance to add the information from the database itself Alex asked for. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo how do I add the JSON file for you to see ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen does it mean according to my code that snapshot does not exist for the values that I am trying to get ?

Comment: @ShaunSingh1410 You can follow my repository on github to get the idea clearly https://github.com/kauramanp/FirebaseRealtimeDbWithRecyclerView/tree/main

Comment: Did Frank's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your `firebaseUser.getUid()` returns `NN3ikr...`, then your `onDataChange` should already be called with the correct snapshot according to your screenshot.

You can get the values of the individual properties with:

```
reference.child("Businesses").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        String businessAbout = snapshot.child("businessAbout").getValue(String.class);
        String businessAddress = snapshot.child("businessAddress").getValue(String.class);
        String businessContactPerson = snapshot.child("businessContactPerspon").getValue(String.class);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was the right way to solve my problem, but it worked :
My database structure was Businesses -> userID -> businessName -> businessAbout.
I changed it so all the children will fall under just userID, that included businessName.

Thank you guys :)